# Storing timestamps in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I remember I read somewhere that mySQL timestamp data type is used to be updated automatically when the row updates, is this true?

Do I have to store timestamps with timestamp datatype or with bigint for example?

NB: the timestamp that has to be stored is not generated by mySQL, it's a pre-defined value that will be generated with PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: you want that when row is updated the timestamp field is automatically updated .

Answer (score 19):

A column of type `TIMESTAMP` can be set to update automatically using `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the column definition.

However, this will not populate on insert of a record. As you have stated, you can build a timestamp in PHP (format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) and insert it, or you can set another column attribute of `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the column definition.

For more information: [MySQL: TIMESTAMP Properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)

**UPDATE:**
If a unix timetstamp value is the required output, store the value using `TIMESTAMP` and then get the unix value using:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_column_name) FROM your_table_name
```

To insert using a unix timestamp, you can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()`

```
INSERT INTO (your_table_name) (your_column_name) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(your_bigint_value));
```

Answer (score 8):

ok I think this is resolved.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

a zero value timestamp looks like this '0000-00-00 00:00:00', so it can't be used to store a unix timestamp like this : 1309347278, so it must be BIGINT.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the `TIMESTAMP` is stored internally using a UNIX timetstamp. MySQL functions are available to get the unix value. If you want the auto update functionality, use TIMESTAMP and query for the unix timestamp using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: **"so it must be BIGINT"**, No it doesn't, it's  an `int(11)`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is `int(11)`, because a timestamp is a **big/large integer**.

Comment: exactly, it is a signed int which largest number is  2147483647 which is the same as  2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 (Limit of timestamp datatype).

I'm curious what will occur after this date. I think this will be changed in upcoming releases. But if you actually have to store values above this limit, then I would recommend to store it as bigint unsigned. Also you can't use it for dates before 1970-01-01.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE `db1`.`sms_queue` (
  `Id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Message` VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown Message Error',
  `CurrentState` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None',
  `Phone` VARCHAR(14) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `LastUpdated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `TriesLeft` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I remember I read somewhere that mySQL timestamp data type is used to be updated automatically when the row updates, is this true?

Yes.

> Do I have to store timestamps with timestamp datatype or with bigint for example?

Timestamp is a datatype. You use it like `latest_update TIMESTAMP(8)` when you create the table.

Answer (score 1):

from MySQL manual:

> By default, the first TIMESTAMP column in a table is automatically set to the date and time of the most recent operation if you do not assign it a value yourself. You can also set any TIMESTAMP column to the current date and time by assigning it a NULL value.